# VB6: Colour portions of points of a star

Tags: api, vb6, colors, polygon, region

I have found API functions to draw a star using VB6: what I need is to colour sections of each point of the star according to data-driven parameters: thus if the parameter passed is 1, I want to colour the part of the selected star point red up to 1/10th of its length measured from the circunference of the circle around which the star is built; if 2, 2/10ths of the star point green, etc.

I have found the API function [CreatePolygonRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183511(VS.85).aspx) so I can change the colour of the whole of a particular star point but baffled as to how a polygon can be defined using only one X and Y parameter: if I change the X and Y for a given star point, I get results that don't seem to make sense
TKIF
Charles Geach
se

Answer (score 1):

The excellent vbAccelerator gives [some VB6 code](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/Code/Libraries/Graphics_and_GDI/Changing_Window_Shapes/Creating_Geometric_Window_Shapes/article.asp). I haven't tested this myself. Be aware that `points()` is an array, and even though it **looks** like you are only passing the first element, you are actually giving the API call access to the **whole** array. The first argument to [CreatePolygonRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183511(VS.85).aspx) is not a single point, but an array of points.

I hope that helps you understand what's going on, and you can get your star code written.

```
Type POINTAPI
  X As Long
  Y As Long
End Type
Declare Function CreatePolygonRgn Lib "gdi32" _
  (lpPoint As POINTAPI, ByVal nCount As Long, _
   ByVal nPolyFillMode As Long) As Long

Sub Test()
  Const ALTERNATE = 1 ' ALTERNATE and WINDING are '
  Const WINDING = 2   ' constants for FillMode. '

   Dim points(1 To 5) as POINTAPI
   ' fill in points .. '
   CreatePolygonRgn(points(1), 5, WINDING)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with API calls, I would like to suggest an alternative.  It sounds to me like you will have (at most) 11 different looking stars (0 to 10).  If this were my project, I would create 11 images using a graphics application of your choice.  Then, depending on the value of the variable, selectively show whichever image you want.